# What is the rate limit of request in AZURE account? [Azure-Storage][REST]

Tags: azure, rest, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an `Azure` storage account and want to know the **rate-limit** for making **REST** requests through it(Read/Write) and also know the number of remaining requests. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling#remaining-requests)

I have this simple code to **List the Blobs** in a container:

```
const request = require("request");  
require("dotenv").config();

const account = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME || "";
const key = process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY || "";
var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();
const containerName = "demo";

const BearerToken = <BearerToken>;

const options = {
  url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}?comp=list&restype=container`,

  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${BearerToken}`,
    "x-ms-date": strTime, //var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();
    "x-ms-version": "2019-02-02", // Stable xms vesrion
  },
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.body);
  console.log(response.headers["x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads"]);
}

request(options, callback);
```

There is no such field in headers. But in this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling#remaining-requests), it is mentioned. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links you mentioned are for `Azure Resource Manager REST API` operations which are free. For `Storage REST API` (like `List Blobs` operation etc.), the equivalent is `Storage Account Throughput`.

For a standard storage account, here's the link that talks about the throughput limitations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json. For example, you can make 20000 requests/second against a standard storage account.

Storage REST API does not expose the rate limit and remaining requests. However if you exceed the throughput quota (for example, make more than 20000 requests/second), Azure Storage Service will start throttling your requests.